# No trusted certificate found when using Java for making request on HTTPS

Tags: linux, java, certificates

I'm a Java developer and I need to use a particular version of java 8 (1.8.0_162) can't use OpenJDK either.

But, I'm getting this error when I try to connect / get / download / whatever from my java program on any **HTTPS url**

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

I know that the code is right, because its working on production, but I can run the code on my local machine.

I think is something related to certificates, but don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

The JDK & JRE ship with their own collection of trusted certificates. This file is named 'cacerts', and it can be found under `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security`. `readlink -f /bin/java` should indicate where the JDK_HOME directory is located.

The cacerts file contains a list of all certificates from trusted Certificate Authorities (CAs). The file is in the JKS format, so you can manipulate it with `keytool` (another command that is part of the JDK). You will need root permissions to modify the file.

Most well-known CAs are already part of the cacerts file. Since you're encountering an exception, the CA certificate used by your HTTPS endpoints must be missing from this file. You'll need to extract the CA certificate from the remote endpoint and add it to the cacerts file. Restart your application afterwards, and it should work as expected.

In case you don't want to modify the cacerts file, it is also possible to set up your own truststore. In this approach, you create a truststore containing the certificates you want to trust, and then use the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` properties to point your application to it.

Comment: thanks, you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in my security folder (`jre/lib/security`) the files inside were broken links to other files that doesn't exists.

I went to the Oracle homepage, download a JDK from Java 8 Linux, and replaced all the files inside the security folder (but no the folder policy).